# Making contracts: on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, site-topic, specific-question

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98886/how-to-define-valid-html-in-a-contract-rfp) was migrated to us, and I rejected based on the content. Some people are asking that it be allowed, and I'd like to get the community's feedback on it.

To me, it's a legal type question, which from my experience, usually results in "check with your contract/lawyer". It may be a good question for Freelancers, but I'd like consensus on it, as a community.

Answer (score 2):

It's merely too broad and opinion-based to me. There's no definitive way to state what "valid" means... it's all just what *I think* would be "valid".

And really.. "valid" could just mean "functional". If someone is using Google Pagespeed as a marker.. they aren't *really* interested in validity, just some form of confirmation, regardless of how inaccurate that confirmation may be.

I think you were right to reject the question. It's just a bad question. And would take considerable discussion between parties to come to an agreement as to what "valid" means.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I am in two minds about this.

The obvious retort to the OP is 'Valid for what?', or 'valid according to which standards'. Given the reference to the equally arbitrary site speed, or the oft disputed W3C, this gives some indication that it is entirely opinion based. This would be better suited to a forum dedicated to HTML or contractual issues, not for the Freelancing stack exchange.

However, if the site continues to reject 'advice' or 'opinion' based questions, I am not sure what it is going to answer. Most valid freelancing questions are never going to be black and white. It will often be not like a maths question or a coding question, where an actual 'right' answer is available.

I can point to lots of great questions on here that could equally have been rejected as opinion based.

So I am in two minds, and although I think there is room for more grey and less black and white on this channel, I do think this question probably overstepped the mark in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that occurred to me reading your question was "It may be a good question for Freelancers".  If there's a chance it would help then I would support the question.